# How to remove kdewallet?

Tags: kde

I recently saved my svn passwords in KDEwallet now everytime I update from svn or commit it asks me for kde password.

How do I either remove the completely the KDEwallet or atleast the svn password from KDE.

I tried using command line `kdewalletmanager` but it says

```
kdewalletmanager: command not found
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Following disabling `kdewallet`. Open and edit `~/.kde/share/config/kwalletrc` as shown below.

```
[$Version]
update_info=kwallet-4.13.upd:kde4.13

[Auto Allow]
kdewallet=kwalletmanager

[Auto Deny]
kdewallet="Google Chrome"

[Wallet]
Enabled=false
Launch Manager=false
```

Comment: This solution works for me even without `[Auto Allow]` section. Using Kubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 5):

You can remove kwalletmanager with

```
sudo apt-get purge kwalletmanager
```

note: its kwalletmanager not kdewalletmanager

If you want to disable it, just open it and go to Settings > Configure Wallet
and uncheck the "Enable the KDE wallet subsystem" box

Comment: posting an image could be more helpful :D

Comment: http://s12.postimage.org/htkzh8qzx/Untitled.gif

Comment: @ican I have attached screen shot above that I get when using svn

Comment: Answer (both suggestions) are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer. Rename the /usr/*/kwallet* to shutthekwalletup

That's it! Might want to clean it up later tho

Answer (score 0):

For me pip installed keyring as some dependency for something and ever since sometimes I randomly get asked to create "kdewallet".

To get rid of that run `pip uninstall keyring`

Answer (score 0):

try to run this

```
sudo apt remove libpam-kwallet5 ibpam-kwallet-common
```